# Possible to reuse hardware remote assignments?

Tags: midi, midi-controller-keyboard, cubase

Is it possible to achieve both *wah position control* and *wah bypass* with the same expression pedal in Cubase 13 Pro (M1)? I’ve mapped the pedal to a quick control which is sent to Helix Native knob 1 to control the wah position (using CC22 coming from the expression pedal), so that works fine. However, how do I make the “heel down” pedal position send a switch 2 command (or possibly another CC numer) to Helix Native so that I can bypass the wah?

If I try to add another mapping for say CC22, then Cubase warns that it is already mapped before going to the mapping assistant. Does this mean it’s not possible in Cubase? Or is there another way to go about this?

Comment: Interesting question. I would guess some MIDI effect is needed to interpret the controller position and send another MIDI message when this value goes below/above some threshold, which then could be assigned to bypass. Have you tried https://steinberg.help/cubase_plugin_reference/v9/en/_shared/topics/plug_ref/transformer_r.html ?